# pseudo class a:focus

Tags: css, css-selectors

Trying to find out more about css pseudo class a:focus Am trying to adapt some code. Have tried

```
a:focus img {border:2px solid rgb(155, 205, 255);}
```

and

```
a:focus img {background:rgb(155, 205, 255);}
```

Neither work. Yet

```
a:hover img {background:rgb(155, 205, 255);}
```

works fine on hover. Does anyone know what I've done wrong?
Les

I am using Firefox, but want this to work cross-browser if possible.
I get a flash but not the steady border like this gallery:
http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/gallery.html#nogo

Comment: It might help to tell us which browser you're using.

Answer (score 0):

<s>If your right click on it to give it focus without actually following the link, does it change?</s>

Comment: Yes. The border stays. What does that mean?

Comment: I coded up a little test, it works for me. Is the site you're working on something public we could look at? Either way, maybe try using !important, in case some other style on your site is overriding the ones you posted. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules

Comment: I hate giving this link, it's my first site and pretty dire. Trying to fix, so pls excuse.
http://www.townsvillemultiples.com.au/photosclk.html
a:focus isn't added as it is not functional. Am working offline to will upload when it works. The relevant css is in the head and I currently have:
    ul#thumbnails li a:hover {background:rgb(145, 225, 235);}
    ul#thumbnails li a:focus img {background:rgb(155, 205, 255);}  
in my offline file.  
(In the online version, you will see only the first line of the above code)

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors seem fine.

A few questions:
What browser are you using?
As Matt said, are you sure you are focusing the  tag?

Comment: Firefox. Added to Q is that wrong to do? The focus works, but it only flashes like hover and active. It should stay until next click.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IE8,

**Note**: Internet Explorer 8 (and higher) supports the `:focus` pseudo-class if a `!DOCTYPE` is specified. (Source: http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_pseudo_focus.asp)

---

**Investigation:** Seeing that you're using Firefox, click on a blank page and press `Tab` on keyboard, with the following CSS:

```
a:focus img {border:2px solid rgb(155, 205, 255); padding: 2px;}
```

See if this works, and report appropriately.

Also, does the `<a>` tag has other pseudo-classes outside of `focus`?

---

Just a suggestion, based on yoru example http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/gallery.html#nogo, they did this:

```
#container a.pics:focus img.thumb {border:1px solid #fc0}
```

Why don't you do this?

```
a img:focus {border:2px solid rgb(155, 205, 255); padding: 2px;}
```

Comment: Using Firefox, but would like best cross-browser result.

Comment: Using tab puts the cursor in FFs URL box. It says:  
"Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol (a) isn't associated with any program."  

<a> tag hover, active and focus set (in that order) Removing hover and active makes no difference. When I right click the thumbnail, the focus stays. Is this good or bad???  

I want it to work like this gallery:  
http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/gallery.html#nogo  
Does that help at all?

Comment: Well, the tutorial on CSS Play, the focus works. Check: http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_classes.asp to see the order of order of `<a>` pseudo-classes (hope this helps you).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like clicking a link that takes you elsewhere on the same page is causing that link to loose focus. Not the most elegant solution, but what I can come up with involves javascript.

For the style:

```
a.selected img{border:9px solid green}
```

And then a script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var last = null;
    function select(element)
    {
        if(last != null)
            last.className = last.className.replace(/ selected/g, "");
        element.className += " selected";
        last = element;
    }
</script>
```

And then add an onclick event handler to each thumbnail link:

```
<li><a href="#pic1" onclick="select(this);"><img src="thumbs/whatever.jpg" alt="whatever" /></a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. Have noted that one down. Have begun with php, but no JS yet, so much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the border on the a tag rather than the image tag inside of it.

Comment: Do you mean  
    ul#thumbnails li a:focus {background:green;}  
This gives the same result. focus works only on right click.  
  
Am following the formatting rules for my comments, but see that it isn't working. Sorry for the lousy formatting - don't know how to fix it.